# Ext.NET how to access file from file upload field inside Panel Code behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

I'm working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` with `EXT.NET`. 
I'm having a file upload field inside panel and I'm making ajax call to upload file on db.
I don't know how to access the file from `fileuploadfield` .

I tried this -

```
HttpPostedFile f = this.getCmp<FileUploadField>("id").PostedFile;
```

but its returning `null`.

i'm able to get the the control but NOT its value.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What is the html source that is generated? Can you see the file input in the source. For example, if the file input is something similar to:

```
<input class="cancel" type="file" name="iFile" id="iFile" style="visibility:hidden" onchange="bb_fileChosen()" accept="image/*"/>
```

Then you can access it and upload it with something like:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "post", '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action( "UploadFileAction", "MyControlller" ))', true ); 

xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" );
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-File-Name", file.name );
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-File-Size", file.size );
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-File-Type", file.type );

// Send the file
xhr.send( $( "#iFile" )[0].files[0] );
```